# Scrolling background showing through overlay div

Tags: css

Here's my code:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: #d28d8d; position: relative; z-index: 1000" />
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y:scroll">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/t8chgkbx/1/

The colored div at the top acts as an overlay. I set the z-index but the text in the div below it still shows through. I don't want this text showing through. Not sure what the problem is. My real problem however is how to allow the user to scroll the content below the overlay when they are scrolling on the overlay.

UPDATE: Bas van Dijk fixed the problem. Seems like you can't use /> on the second line but must use . That's weird. Anyways, my real code doesn't have this problem because I do use the closing div. But back to my real issue. I want to allow the user to scroll on the header which simply passes the scroll event down to the div beneath it.

Comment: I posted an answer without `pointer-events` please check may be it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched the absolute and relative for both divs: https://jsfiddle.net/t8chgkbx/5/

```
<div style="position: relative">
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: #d28d8d; position: absolute; z-index: 1000"></div>
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y:scroll">
```

And added `put pointer-events:none` to overlay as described in the comments

Comment: You got it to work. Thanks. But now my real problem is that when you scroll on the overlay, the scrolling in the div below does not work. I want to have the scroll events that occur on the overlay to bubble down to the overlay.

Comment: Found the solution. Need to put pointer-events:none on the overlay.

Comment: Ok! I've updated my answer and learned about pointer-events, didn't knew it existed :)

Answer (score 0):

can you take your text div out of outer div like this
:-

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: #d28d8d; position: absolute; z-index: 3000" />
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y:scroll">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>11</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>13</p>
  <p>14</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. The jsfiddle code is a simplified version of my real code which does in fact hide the lower text (just don't know why it doesn't do it in the sample I've provided). Once I get the overlay problem in fiddle to work, I want to address my real issue which is to get scrolling to work when it occurs on the overlay.